# Need to fix if else script

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I wanted to make a script which should take an argument and check if it is equal to a given word and then display a message accordingly. I use the bash shell of ubuntu OS. I tried something as per the tutorial - http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/209/bournebash-shell-scripts-string-comparison/ and it failed.

```
#!/bin/bash
if ["$1"=="password"]
then
echo correct password
else
echo wrong password
fi
```

> bash Script.sh password.

error message is - 
[password=password]: command not found.

How to fix it ?

Comment: Is this a bad question ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whitespaces:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" == "password" ]
then
echo correct password
else
echo wrong password
fi
```

The expression after the `if` is actually a command, and commands are delimited by whitespaces. So your command is `["$1"=="password"]` that expands to `[password==password]`, that obiously does not exist (`/usr/bin/[password==password]` anyone?).

In my corrected code, the command is `[` (yes, there is a `/bin/[`) and the rest of the line are the arguments.

See `man test` for details (`test` is a kind-of-alias for `[`).

Comment: `[` is a synonym for the `test` command, not syntax (although it simulates syntax so much that, unlike `test`, a final argument of `]` is required), so it must be separated from its arguments like all commands